# How to check if a font supports a specific style

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

I'm getting the following exception when changing my application font, because I use a strike out in a part of my application, and some fonts don't support it:

[image]

I change my application font using a font dialog. I need to **check if the selected font supports the strikeout style** after assigning it to my application.

What is the recommended way to do this? I know I could create a font with the style and catch the exception, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**: The user selects a font, not necesary strikeout. In that moment I need to check if the font supports the style strikeout, because I create a strikeout font in a part of my application. If the font don't support the strikeout style would not allow the user to choose that font.

Comment: The exception is all you got.  Nothing to worry about, it is exceptional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the following:

```
    private bool SupportStrikeout(Font font)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Font strikeout = new Font(font, FontStyle.Strikeout))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated :** (to reflect update in the initial post):

```
InstalledFontCollection ifc = new InstalledFontCollection();
for (int i = 0; i < ifc.Families.Length; i++)
    {
         if (ifc.Families[i].IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.StrikeOut))
         {
             //add particular font with this family to your "font selector"
         }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explained my question correctly. See my edits

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard `Font` class, then you can use the [Font.Strikeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.strikeout.aspx) property:

```
//Gets a value that indicates whether this Font specifies a horizontal line through the font.
public bool Strikeout { get; }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explained my question correctly. See my edits

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba You can create Font object for User select, and get the value of the Property. If it is `false`, then you have to forbid the font seleciton.

Comment: See the Andrei answer, something like that is what I mean.

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba Did his answer help you?